# Acessar os valores dados pelo função "boot"

Tags: r

estou tendo um problema em conseguir pegar alguns valores dados pela função `boot` no R:

Meus dados

```
dados<- c(16483.82, 16463.06, 15649.35, 15615.27, 20034.44, 16254.43, 16946.72)
meanFunc <- function(x,i){mean(x[i])}
 bootMean <-(boot(data=x,statistic=meanFunc,R=1000))
```

Após isto, eu faço `> bootMean` e o resultado é o seguinte:

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP

Call:
boot(data = x, statistic = meanFunc, R = 1000)

Bootstrap Statistics :

    original        bias     std. error
t1* 16778.16  -0.9335903     540.371
```

Peguei parte desses códigos [neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341569/r-calculate-the-standard-error-using-bootstrap)

Tentei converter para um data frame mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma possível solução [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692682/values-of-bootstrap-statistics), então caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema uma maneira de resolver e esta.

```
bias<- mean(bootMean$t) - bootMean$t0    
desviopadrao<- sd(bootMean$t)

original<-bootMean$t0
```

Comment: Você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita nesse caso.

Answer (score 0):

1) se vc quer saber o conteudo de um objeto (e portanto os campos) a solucao é usar o `str`

```
> str(bootMean)
List of 11
 $ t0       : num 16778
 $ t        : num [1:1000, 1] 16692 17501 16776 17648 16184 ...
 $ R        : num 1000
 $ data     : num [1:7] 16484 16463 15649 15615 20034 ...
 $ seed     : int [1:626] 403 1 235491040 177295907 312278337 450969648 1593694798 259661497 1711303371 -2124436614 ...
 $ statistic:function (x, i)  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")=Class 'srcref'  atomic [1:8] 1 13 1 37 13 37 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment:0x102c7ce28> 
 $ sim      : chr "ordinary"
 $ call     : language boot(data = dados, statistic = meanFunc, R = 1000)
 $ stype    : chr "i"
 $ strata   : num [1:7] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ weights  : num [1:7] 0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143 0.143 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "boot"
```

2) Eu uso o `boot` em conjunto com o `boot.ci` para obter o intervalo de confianca (o tchans de um metodo como bootstrap nao é obter a media - que deve ser bem similar a media obtida com o `mean`, mas sim o intervalo de confianca).

Mas obter os resultados do `boot.ci` nao é direto é preciso ler a secao value do manual 
http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/functions/boot.ci

```
> bci<-boot.ci(bootMean)
Warning message:
In boot.ci(bootMean) : bootstrap variances needed for studentized intervals
> bci$bca[4:5]
[1] 16074.65 18516.44
```